# JQuery how to remove element based on content of sub-element

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

[image]

I'm trying to write JQuery to remove all divisions with class `item ui-draggable...` based on the value of the highlighted element. For instance check if the value is less than 100, and if true, remove the division.
I have no idea how to do this, however. The structure of all the divisions are the same. The relevant number will always be contained in the 6th sub-element of the division to be removed.

so in pseudo-code I want to write this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    for each division of class .item ui-draggable... {
       if (value of relevant number < 100) {
          .remove(division);
       }
    }
});
```

Comment: If you are looking to learn the basics of jQuery, may I suggest the following sites: [jQuery docs](http://api.jquery.com/), [CodeAcademy](http://www.codecademy.com/), [Tuts+](http://tutsplus.com/), [KhanAcademy](https://www.khanacademy.org/computing/computer-programming), [Resources list](http://zachsaucier.com/blog/resources.html), [Mozilla Docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.item.ui-draggable').each(function(){
       var val = parseInt($(this).find('.socialMetaCount').text(),10);
       if (val < 100) { 
          $(this).remove();
       }
    })
});
```

Comment: This was more simple for me to understand. And it works perfect! :)

Comment: @user2651804 glad to help U, this is more simple but if you have time later check well the answer from David. The filter() use can be helpfull on future.

Answer (score 5):

First select the elements you want to assess, and then, if those elements meet the criteria, move up to the relevant element with `closest()` or `parents()`, and remove those:

```
$('em.socialMetaCount').filter(function(){
    return parseInt(this.textContent.trim(), 10) < 100;
}).closest('.item.ui-draggable').remove();
```

References:

- JavaScript:

  - [`parseInt()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseInt).
  - [`String.prototype.trim()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/Trim).
- jQuery:

  - [`closest()`](http://api.jquery.com/closest/).
  - [`filter()`](http://api.jquery.com/filter/).

Comment: Nice this seems more effective and faster ... +1

Answer (score 0):

So in code you wanted to write is

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".item ui-draggable").each(function(){
       if (anyNumber< 100 && somethingTrue) {
          $(this).remove();
       }
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I think that what you are looking for is something like this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".ui-draggable").each(function() {
        if (parseInt($(this).find('.socialMetaCount').text()) < 100) {
            $(this).remove();
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: An `em` has no `value` property (therefore can't use the `val()` method), you'd need to use `text()` instead. Then the retrieved text would be a string (not a number) so the comparison would likely not-work (as expected).

Comment: Thanks David, I updated the solution with your comment. Although I think the solution you propose is better than mine for this task.